# Parse viable for a iOS social network application

Tags: ios, parse-platform, social-networking, backend

I was wondering if parse would be a viable option for having around 200,000 users a month with a couple tens if thousands users at once. Parse seems very easy to use and to implement, but I cannot tell if it is very scalable. Would parse be a good option for the type of social network I am looking for or would it be smarter and safer to create my own custom php server for the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is built to be scalable, so the most likely obstacle you face will be designing your data model. If you have a SQL background (or if you build your backend in SQL), your backend will be more likely to suffer from scalability issues.

Social services like twitter do not build their backend on SQL-based databases, for scalability reasons.

Going through the Anypic tutorial and code, is a good primer. I would also recommend checking out the Twissandra project (a Java-based twitter-clone for Cassandra) just for understanding the conceptual differences when working with NoSQL vs SQL.

Good luck!

Comment: I was also wondering if there was a significant difference between using parse or google app engine and google cloud as the backend for it. I was curious if google app engine would be good for a social network or if parse was a better solution.